# Uniformly autosizing multiple TextViews

Tags: android, textview, kotlin, autosize

In my activity I have three textviews with autosizing (not using support library):

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="1, Jan"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_horizontal_date_time"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView_time"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextClock
            android:id="@+id/textView_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12:00 AM"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_horizontal_date_time"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView_day"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView_date"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_day"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Monday"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline_horizontal_date_time"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView_time"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

When I run this, I get the following result
[image: Uneven text size]

How can I make the date and day textview be of uniform size?
I don't want to set an equal android:autoSizeMaxTextSize property in order to do that.

I have tried the following logic (Kotlin)

```
if(view_date.textSize>view_day.textSize)
            view_date.textSize = view_day.textSize
else
            view_day.textSize=view_date.textSize
```

However it doesn't work, the text size does not get changed.

Comment: Any good solution? I'm interested

Comment: @SirKnigget Sorry I dropped this project midway and iirc I switched to constant size values.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of autosizing is to give the Android framework to decide what text size should be chozen, depends on the screen size.

In you case I would change the way of implementation. You can use one TextView instead of 3 chained one after another, and use [Formatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) method to populate the date/time/day of week. That way the text will be always same size.

Comment: That doesn't help in the case where you really need multiple separate uniform text fields (lists...)